# New badge idea for SE sites: Site Conceiver

Tags: feature-request, area-51, badge-request

If your site proposal results in a site that goes live, you get a special badge, like "Site Conceiver" or something to that effect.  You would be the only one on that site with that badge.

Answer (score 3):

-1.  These sites are supposed to be about the community, not individuals, and badges are supposed to encourage good behavior.  The proposer's name is already highlighted on Area 51, and proposers can already earn A51 badges for various proposal-related things.  I don't see a purpose for `Site Conceiver` that isn't already served.

Comment: +1... though it would be nice for the proposer to get credit somewhere on the site... like in the FAQ or something.

Comment: @George, I wouldn't be adamantly opposed to a mention in the FAQ, but I think the A51 mention is enough; the bulk of the work is really done by followers, committers and question writers.

Comment: I like the thought but I also see Popular Demands point.

Comment: Even the FAQ seems wrong; if people really want credit the /about page is probably most logical